# Without k8s cluster, how to deploy milvus distributed cluster on multiple machines?

Tags: deployment, milvus

If I don't have a k8s cluster, I need to deploy a Milvus distributed cluster on multiple machines. How should I do this? Is it possible to use the docker-compose way?